# Looping through an array

Tags: javascript, node.js

Trying to do simple js and not sure where im going wrong, trying to make a link for each array item

```
app.get('/list', function(req, res){
    fs.readdir(__dirname + "/files", function (err, files) {
        if (err) throw err;

         var items = ["a", "b", "c"]; //using items opposed to files for demostration
         for( var i=0;i<items.length;i++){
             res.send('<a href="#">'+items[i]+'</a>');
         } 
    }); 
});
```

and its just returning the first item as a link, is there something different that I should be doing with nodejs?

Comment: You can simplify it a little using Underscore: `links = _.reduce(items, function (memo, item) { return memo + '<a href="#">' + item + '</a>'; }, '');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Build the links, and then send them all, like this:

```
fs.readdir(__dirname + "/files", function (err, files) {
    var items, links;
    if (err) throw err;

    items = ["a", "b", "c"];
    links = '';
    items.forEach(function(item) { // native array foreach.
        links += '<a href="#">' + item + '</a>';
    });

    res.send(links);
});
```